# Are androids such as David in AI meant to grow up?

Tags: ai-artificial-intelligence

It just now occurred to me after watching the film many times whether the intention was for people to purchase a perpetual child (which some people would want) or a robot that eventually somehow became an adult (what if he is the David in Prometheus??) which seems less likely or finally, a robot that you kept around until you got tired of it but never got any older. I am pretty sure this was not addressed at all. At the same time, they show his creator to be a humane person who would probably not intend for his creations to be discarded.

Comment: I’m not clear how your third option is different from your first.

Comment: the third option was rather than intending to hang onto the robot which never changed the people planned to get rid of it because they expected to get bored of it after a while -- it is the initial intention of the buyer.

Comment: The UK show *Humans* has an interesting take on it in season 2. TLDW: you swap models every year or two.  Note in that world, synthetics wear out, and a 5-year-old synthetic is considered very old or obsolete.

Comment: I think that it would be more logical to make "little Orphen Annie" robots which might originally only love their first "parents" but might also get close to other people, enough to make a decent child.  Somone could say that Little Orphan Annie only loved Daddy Warbucks, but she did get along with a lot of people she met in her adventures and many of them took her in and would have adopted her if she could not return to Daddy Warbucks.  I think that real human children can gradually learn to love persons other than their first family, so why not reusable child robots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David and his ilk are ageless. That's one of the main attractions.

> **HOBBY:** *Ours will be a perfect child caught in a freeze-frame -
> always loving, never ill, never changing. With all the
> childless couples yearning in vain for a license, our little
> mecha would not only open an entirely new market, it will
> fill a great human need.*

Note that David cannot just be *discarded* or resold. If the decision is made not to keep him after imprinting, a contract has been signed that he needs to be returned to the factory to be "destroyed".

> **Henry:** *Because of this, after imprinting, no mecha child can be resold. If an adoptive parent should ever decide not to keep the child, they must return it to Cybertronics for destruction.*

Comment: Interesting. But is it implied that they will be destroyed or wiped if, for example, both parents died or they just got tired of having a child who never matured for years and years? I mean, in fact we do know that the robot will be recycled or whatever but do they expect that to be the usual thing -- you keep a mecha for 3-5 years and then turn him in?

Comment: @releseabe - That was also addressed in the film - **Henry:** *Because of this, after imprinting, no mecha child can be
resold. If an adoptive parent should ever decide not to keep
the child, they must return it to Cybertronics for destruction*. That's why Monica dumps him on the way to the factory.

Comment: My instinct is that they expected the child to be owned for the life of the parent.

Comment: Right, of course I recall that once imprinted they have to be destroyed (although I did not recall that term and I am sure they would re-use his parts). But this makes it inevitable that someday the robot will be destroyed in which case why not program in mortality? Or make them reprogrammable?

Comment: I think the destruction indicates something very different about their minds -- ironically that because they not purely "machines" (as we understand them) they can't simply be wiped so they must be destroyed. That is sort of poignant, ain't it? Maybe they should not create such minds or maybe we have no right to destroy them. Maybe that was the theme?

Comment: @releseabe - The robot researcher lady at the start makes precisely that point. - https://youtu.be/1tWVs7VbO-4?t=140  ***"If a robot could genuinely love a person, what responsibility does that person hold toward that mecha in return"***

Comment: Forced obsolescence tends to be viewed poorly by consumers; even when they don't intend to keep an item forever, they want to have that option. And I don't think there's really a firm explanation of why the robots can't be reprogrammed, but it is possible that the process can't be easily "rewritten", such as AI systems where there's neural pruning involved.